# SQL Server datetime convert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert these `varchars` to `datetime`. I've been to the microsoft page and don't see a style that is applicable to this format.

How would you convert these to datetime?

Format: `yyyy-mm-dd`

Example data: `2010-09-04`

Thanks a lot

Comment: The characters you've included in your question are not a valid date and time. They are simply a format. Are you trying to write a `DateTime` using that format?

Comment: updated the question to include an example.  thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST('2010-09-04' as DateTime)
```

returns `2010-09-04 00:00:00.000`

Sql Server 2008

Comment: @cobolstinks : yep take a five :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you specify the format of the date, in your case, 120.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2010-09-04',120)
```